# Flutter Intl - the getter was called on null

Tags: flutter, internationalization, flutter-intl

I am attempting to internationalize a flutter application using the Android Studio/VS Code Flutter Intl plugin.  I can get the S.of(context).value to work throughout the app in widgets I've made myself and basic Text widgets but when I use it in Flutter widgets (Text Form field, list tile, drop down menu item, dropdown button, etc) I get the "NoSuchMethodError: the getter 'value' was called on null.  It seems like there might be an issue between the static pieces of the Flutter widgets and the dynamic nature of the internationalized text?

Is there a way to correct this without making all of my own widgets?

Comment: Hello,
just runnning into the same here.....
did you solve this?

Comment: I haven't.  We've put our internationalization on hold for now